# Does a function call in the Where(...) clause of a Linq to Nhibernate query negatively affect performance?

Tags: linq, performance, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, linq-expressions

I use linq to nhibernate and the IQueryable.Where function in an application I'm building.   And what mystifies me is how do the `Expression`s I create and pass to the Where function of a INhibernateQueryable affect performance.

I'm not really sure what are the gotchas I should avoid in writing these query Expressions, in terms of performance.  If I pass in an expression with a function call like:

```
CurrentSession.Linq<ENTITY>().Where(x => x.IsBuyOrder && CheckVariousProperties(x))
```

Is it going to retrieve every record `where IsBuyOrder = true` and then call the function `CheckVariousProperties` on them as soon as the deferred execution is no longer deferred?

How do function calls affect LinqToNhibernate performance?

What kind of things should be avoided in a LINQ to Nhibernate query Expression?

Comment: I think it's easier to write a quick test to verify this.

Comment: Well that maybe true, and I may do that, but I wanted to see if someone with a detailed knowledge could explain some of the things to look out for.

Answer (score 0):

I would eliminate the `CheckVariousProperties(x)` from the query portion and apply it to the returned result of the query.

```
var myresult= [object].Where(x => x.IsUBuyOrder);
var checkedResult = myresult.Where(x => CheckVariousProperties(x));
```

Comment: thanks for the response, are you saying this will perform better? why?

Comment: I believe this won't change anything since I think the queries are combined - unless you call ToList() on the first query.

Comment: I'm not even sure combining them would work- wouldn't it have to return the data first, then execute the CheckVariousProperties?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to profile you're application using [NHibernate Profiler](http://www.nhprof.com/).  It will be able to help you identify your biggest bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll use it. I was wondering though, do know how linq to nhibernate handles function calls in expressions?